# if the gcd of (a,b) = 1, and a,b divide an integer x, prove that ab ≤x

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

A simple doubt regarding GCDs:

If $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, $a\vert x$ and $b\vert x$, how do we prove that $ab\le x $?

I was attempting the proof of this theorem:
If $\gcd(a,b) = 1,  a\vert x$ and $ b\vert x$, prove that $ab\vert x$.

And proving the above mentioned inequality will complete my proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a|x then x=ka
For each p^i prime factor of b, p^i | x.
But since gcd(a,b)=1, p^i | k.
So k>=b, and result follows